# why jscript does not work in Chrome browser on iOS 7?

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome

Please explain me why my simple script does not work in Chrome browser on iOS 7.
It works in safari, android devices, desktop browser BUT not in ios chrome...

Browser says nothing... not an error, no the message.

Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      alert("11");
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap `11` in quotes:

```
alert("11");
```

Comment: no effect... double quotes, single quotes... no effect. The question was edited to make it with quotes. Thanks.

Comment: Did you specify the `doctype`?

Comment: Try to use `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` which is HTML5 doctype

Comment: my script ONLY works if I place it inside <body>... Why? Is it rule I do not know?